# Keep history of changes on an excel table to another sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to create a dashboard in excel 2010 for my department that will be as much automated as possible. So, I have a table, with data that will be updated in each cell every month or week. Now my problem is that, when someone goes and changes the value of a cell to the new value for the new month, I don't want to lose the previous value of the previous month.

Is there any possible way to save automatically every time the values of the cells in the table, by keeping all the old ones? More specifically, I would like to keep a copy of the entire history of the table, for example for 12 months into a different sheet. I have used a code in VBA so far that saves the row that every change happens, but it's not expanding, i.e., when a change happens in another row, the changes will be displayed in exactly the same place where was the previous history. Also, the function is triggered immediately once I click the cell. I would prefer the function to store the data only when a change has been made in the cell-value. 
Is there anyone who can help me resolve this problem?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Without any knowledge of what your table looks like, or how big and complex it is,  here are two options:

**1. Pre-Generate tabs**

IF the changes are always made on the same interval (i.e.  Monthly, weekly, etc...), why not create a workbook that has separate tabs for each interval at which you make changes?  For example, If you update the cells monthly, have a tab for each month.

Just have each sheet reference the one before.  So, each cell in the February table will display whatever is in each cell of the January table, until you update the cells.  Then the March table will automatically reference February's table, and so on.  This is a simple way to do it and will work as long as your team is competent enough to update the correct tab.

**2. Create a macro**

Another option would be to create a macro that will automatically duplicate the sheet containing your table, name it as the current date and time, and move it to the end.  you can then link the macro to a button, so after one makes the necessary updates to the "master table," he or she would just click the button.  Such a macro might look like this:

```
Sub SaveTable()

Dim CurrentDate As String, CurrentTime As String

CurrentDate = Format(Date, "MMM DD, YYYY")
CurrentTime = Format(Time, "HHMM")

Sheets("Table").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
Sheets(Worksheets.Count).Name = CurrentDate & " " & CurrentTime

End Sub
```

Simply replace "Table" with whatever you want to name your master sheet.